# Functional Programming: Odd number check

Tags: haskell

I was performing a odd number check on this Haskell function and although it does work with positive numbers when it comes to negative numbers it returns an error..

```
myodd :: Integer -> Bool
myodd = rem n 2 == 1
```

I thought it would work if I place the abs somewhere.. like this:

```
myodd :: Integer -> Bool
myodd = rem (abs(n)) 2 == 1
```

but I still receive an error when placing negative numbers..

I don't know what else I could do... any idea would be very appreciated :)

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Please post real code. The code you posted won't compile, and thus will not work for either positive or negative numbers.

Comment: Even after your edit, the code won't compile. Test your code before posting it! And you still haven't posted the error message either.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson when i give    -1  it returns the following error:    

ERROR - Cannot infer instance
*** Instance   : Num (Integer -> Bool)
*** Expression : myodd - 1

Comment: @interjay  it did compile. But it doesn't accept negative numbers.

Comment: Maybe the code you actually ran did compile. But the code you posted here will not.

Comment: @nubz0r You get that error because `myodd` is a function, not a number, so you can't subtract one from it. If you want to call `myodd` with `-1` as its argument, write `myodd (-1)` - `myodd - 1` (or `myodd -1`, which is the same) means subtraction. That has nothing to do with how `myodd` is defined - it's just Haskell's syntax.

Comment: @sepp2k you are totally right. That was the problem right there. Now it works.. Thanks everyone for all your help! I appreciate it. n1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, your code won't compile. `myodd :: rem (abs(n)) 2 == 1` isn't legal syntax (and neither is `myodd :: rem n 2 == 1`) because `::` should be followed by a type, not an expression (and anyway, you already gave a type signature in the preceding line). To define `myodd` you should use `=` and you should give it a parameter named `n` because you use `n` in the body:

```
myodd :: Integer -> Bool
myodd n = rem (abs(n)) 2 == 1
```

Now this code compiles and works exactly like you want it to. No runtime error will occur if you call it with a negative number.

Comment: @sepp2k I'm sorry I totally mistyped the second line.. it should've been written exactly like yours.

Answer (score 5):

You could check if the result is not equal to 0 (instead if it is equal to 1).

```
myodd :: Integer -> Bool
myodd n = n `rem` 2 /= 0
```

Comment: But in haskell, != is called /=

Comment: Corrected. This is a source of constant annoyance, for me at least.

Comment: @Ingo Don't get annoyed, edit the language! Why not put `infix 4 !=` and `x != y = x /= y` at the top of stuff you write?

Answer (score 4):

The rem function doesn't change the sign of the result, so if you start with a negative number, you get a negative number back. If you want to get only positive numbers, use the mod function, which calculates the mathematically correct modulus:

```
>>> (-3) `rem` 4
-3
>>> (-3) `mod` 4
1
```

Comment: While that's true, the OP's solution of using `abs` works perfectly fine as well.